# AngularJS unit tests, firebasesimplelogin, mocking login service, expect constans

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, firebase

I have spent last week trying to figure out how unit tests works and how  to test my app. I have (maybe) finally managed to create my first test!

[This is how my app.js file looks like and how the login module looks like.](https://gist.github.com/TrkiSF2/11214651)

And this is how my test looks like:

```
'use strict';

describe('Test app configurations', function () {


beforeEach(module('alApp'));

var loginServiceMock = {
    init: function() {
        return {
            user: null
        };
    }
};

beforeEach(function(){
    module('login');
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('loginService', loginServiceMock);
    });
});

it('should have some constants setted up', inject(function ($injector) {
    var loginRedirectPath = $injector.get('loginRedirectPath');
    ...
    var DEFAULTPICTURE = $injector.get('DEFAULTPICTURE');

    expect(loginRedirectPath).toBe('/signin');
            ...
    expect(DEFAULTPICTURE).toBe('anonym.png');
}));

it('should have $rootScope.auth.user equals null', inject(function($rootScope) {
    expect($rootScope.auth.user).toBeNull();
}));
```

});

I have mocked firebase simple login to just return an empty user object because when I check the $rootScope.auth object in console in real browser after the page is loaded it's empty as well.

**I would like to ask if this test is written the good way? Or did I something wrong? Some bad practise?**

Btw the test is green.

Comment: Check out [MockFirebase](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase)